# SQL Server AutoShrink option on database

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

When the `AutoShirnk` option on a database (not log files) is set to `TRUE`, how often does the `AutoShirnk` operation take place?

Is there a set time at which this operation takes occurs? Or does this depend on the size of the database and if so how?

PS: I realize that having the `AutoShirnk` option turned is not a best practice and results in fragmented indexes etc.

Comment: Its a part of a bigger question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141795/sql-server-query-time-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no set time. As per msdn,

> The Database Engine periodically examines the space usage in each database. If a database has the AUTO_SHRINK option set to ON, the Database Engine reduces the size of the files in the database. This activity occurs in the background and does not affect any user activity within the database.

Comment: Thanks! But even though that post claims that this process doesn't affect user activity within the database, looks like it does. And i am trying to troubleshoot. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141795/sql-server-query-time-out

Comment: Also, is there any way to (1) find out the definition of 'periodically' in the text above. And (2) what factors in the 'disk space usage' determines if it's due for a shrink?

Comment: I looked at the other question you posted. By any chance, do you have AUTO GROW set to ON as well? Go through this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315512

Comment: In addition, you will get a lot of answers here- http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/auto-shrink-turn-it-off/

Comment: I do have `AutoGrowth` set turned on for all the data files and the log file. 

- For the Primary data file, it is: By 1MB, Unlimited.
- For 10 of the data files it is: By 100 MB unlimited.
- For 4 of the data files it is: By 50MB, Unlimited
- For the log it is: By 10%, Limited to 2GB

Any issue this might cause?

Comment: Autogrowth with Auto Shrink is a **deadly combo**!! Auto Shrink can trigger Auto growth which might cause IO contention. Please go through the links I posted.